# ¿Cómo puedo reproducir un vídeo con formato mkv con setVideoUri en android?

Tags: android

Trato de hacer una app que reproduzca vídeos en formato `mkv` con el método

```
setVideoUri(Uri.Parse("url"));
```

Pero no puedo hacer que muestre nada. Encontré algo en la página de `android` que dice algo de codificación `VP8`, no sé si tendrá algo que ver eso.

PD: reproduce el formato `3gp` pero no el `mkv`.

Answer (score 1):

Para esto lo primero que debemos de hacer es crear una carpeta "raw" esto para poder almacenar nuestros vídeos android por defecto la detecta como una carpeta contenedora de multitudinaria:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

-> Después de eso iremos a nuestro layout y en mi caso en vez de usar botones para reproducir un vídeo estoy usando imágenes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/videoView_video"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity = "center_horizontal"
    android:scrollbars="none">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src = "@drawable/moon"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ivMoon"
            />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src = "@drawable/skull"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ivSkull"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:src = "@drawable/wolf"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:id="@+id/ivWolf"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Stop"
    android:id="@+id/btnStop"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Antes de poder agregar esto si lo deseas seguir de esta forma debes de agregar imágenes en a la carpeta drawable: 
NT: todas las imágenes deben de ir en minúsculas de preferencia.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora en nuestra clase de java perteneciente al layout debemos de hacer los siguiente:
1.- Comprobamos que pertenezcamos con todas estas importaciones:

- import android.net.Uri;
- import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
- import android.os.Bundle;
- import android.view.View;
- import android.widget.Button;
- import android.widget.ImageView;
- import android.widget.Toast;
- import android.widget.VideoView;

En caso de no poseer algunas de estas importaciones se deberan de importar.
Lo siguiente es ir a la public class y agregar lo siguiente:

```
public class PlayVideo extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{
```

Después de eso debemos de declarar unas variables que coincidan con los elementos que hemos declarado en nuestro layout:

```
ImageView img1, img2,img3,img4,img5;
VideoView play;
Uri path;
Button stop;
```

A continuación crearemos un método para poder detener el vídeo que se esta reproduciendo en el VideoView:

```
 private View.OnClickListener OkListener = new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Stop();
    }
};
```

Dentro del método que se crea dentro de nuestra clase java por defecto haremos lo siguiente relacionamos las variables anteriormente creadas con las correspondientes dentro del layout:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video);

    play = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView_video);
    img1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivWolf);
    img2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivSkull);
    img3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivMoon);
    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnStop);

    img1.setOnClickListener(this);
    img2.setOnClickListener(this);
    img3.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(OkListener);
}
```

SetOnclickListener es un método que crearemos con el fin de poder indicar que cada que se de click sobre la imagen o botón que hemos creado cumplirá una determinada funcion.

A continuación vemos la sintaxis de OnClickListener, este método se debe de implementar cuando nosotros agregamos:

```
implements View.OnClickListener
```

Sintaxis de OnClickListener:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.ivWolf:
            path = Uri.parse("android.resource://twinwingscompany.reproducirvideo/" + R.raw.zero);
            play.setVideoURI(path);
            play.requestFocus();
            play.start();
            break;
        case R.id.ivSkull:
            path = Uri.parse("android.resource://twinwingscompany.reproducirvideo/" + R.raw.box);
            play.setVideoURI(path);
            play.requestFocus();
            play.start();
            break;
        case R.id.ivMoon:
            path = Uri.parse("android.resource://twinwingscompany.reproducirvideo/" + R.raw.onenight);
            play.setVideoURI(path);
            play.requestFocus();
            play.start();
            break;
    }
}
```

Y por último agregamos la función del botón de stop que detendrá la reproducción del vídeo:

```
private void Stop(){
    if(play.isPlaying()){
        play.pause();
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"No hay reproduccion iniciada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    }
}
```

}

Toast es parte de android el cual nos deja lanzar un mensaje en caso de que falle o indique que una acción funciono correctamente

Anexo imagen general en caso de dudas en el orden de los métodos y eventos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que esto resuelva tu problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por toda la explicación, pero lo que intento hacer es que reproduzca desde un servidor el video mkv usando el método setVideoUri, me funciona con mp4 y 3gp pero con el mkv no, solo se queda el fondo del videoView y nada más, no reproduce ni hace nada.